# Kendo UI Grid Excel Export exporting twice

Tags: javascript, excel, kendo-ui

I wrote up some javascript code to export an excel grid that would only export the records filtered on the page by the filter tab and not the total value of records brought back. So for example if the record pulls back 23 records but you only have the view set to 10 you'll only get 10 records exported. I'm loading this function on the grid initialization as I usually do, however, for some reason it always seems to print out an empty sheet first with just the header rows, followed by the actual sheet I need. So the code is working but I can't figure out how to stop the first empty sheet from downloading as well. I don't believe I'm calling the method twice and there's definitely no looping logic... I've read over the Telerik documentation and I figured I'd come to stackoverflow since the Telerik support team just seems to refer everyone back to the same documentation

```
        excelExport: function (e) {
        var items = grid.dataSource.pageSize();
        sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
        var newSheet = sheet.rows.splice(0, items + 1) // +1 is for the header row
        sheet.rows = newSheet
    },
```

Comment: Can you create a more specific sample code, using codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: Top of my head, do you have a class called k-grid-excel on the button that may be triggering one? Maybe e.preventDefault(); as well?